# How to check the number of characters 'M' in a list of datasets using python

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures

I was trying to find out how many 'M' appear in a dataset.
The dataset was like this.

```
dataset = ['Braund, Mr. Owen Harris',
'Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)',
'Heikkinen, Miss. Laina',
'Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)',
'Allen, Mr. William Henry',
'Moran, Mr. James',
'McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J',
'Palsson, Master. Gosta Leonard',
'Johnson, Mrs. Oscar W (Elisabeth Vilhelmina Berg)',
'Nasser, Mrs. Nicholas (Adele Achem)',
'Sandstrom, Miss. Marguerite Rut',
'Bonnell, Miss. Elizabeth',
'Saundercock, Mr. William Henry',
'Andersson, Mr. Anders Johan',
'Vestrom, Miss. Hulda Amanda Adolfina',
'Hewlett, Mrs. (Mary D Kingcome) ',
'Rice, Master. Eugene',
'Williams, Mr. Charles Eugene',
'Vander Planke, Mrs. Julius (Emelia Maria Vandemoortele)',
'Masselmani, Mrs. Fatima',
'Fynney, Mr. Joseph J',
'Beesley, Mr. Lawrence',
'McGowan, Miss. Anna "Annie"',
'Sloper, Mr. William Thompson',
'Palsson, Miss. Torborg Danira',
'Asplund, Mrs. Carl Oscar (Selma Augusta Emilia Johansson)',
'Emir, Mr. Farred Chehab',
'Fortune, Mr. Charles Alexander',
'Dwyer, Miss. Ellen "Nellie"',
'Todoroff, Mr. Lalio']
```

I solved this problem by using for loop and if conditional.

```
count = 0
for data in dataset:
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if data[i] == 'M':
            count += 1
print (count)
```

However, I want to solve it differently by using the string built-in function 'count'. In the above code, since the variable 'data' is string data, I thought that the built-in function 'count' could be used.
I checked by using type(), whether the variable 'data' is a string or not.

So, I used 'count', and below is the code that I wrote.

```
for data in dataset:
    print(data.count('M'))
```

But, the result wasn't what I expected.
These are the results.

```
1
1
1
2
1
2
2
1
1
1
2
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
2
2
1
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

As you can see, the result is the number of 'M's for each string in the dataset we covered earlier. And I'm struggling now with how to add up every number in the result.

I tried to figure it out by using 'list'. After putting all the results into the list, I tried to add all the values in the list with a 'for loop'. However, the only value in the list was the number 1.

```
list1 = []
list1 = data.count('M')
print(list1)
```

Is there any way to solve the problem using the 'count' built-in function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list1 = []
list1 = data.count('M')
```

`list1 = []` isn't doing anything here since you immediately overwrite `list1` on the next line. What you meant was:

```
list1 = []
for data in dataset:
    list1.append(data.count('M'))
```

Or, more idiomatically:

```
list1 = [data.count('M') for data in dataset]
```

Then, you just need to `sum` the numbers:

```
m_sum = sum(list1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count), and a generator expression:

```
total = sum(s.count("M") for s in dataset)
```